# When does "Argument 2 of WebGLRenderingContext.uniform4fv could not [...]" appear using three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to extend a JS game that uses Three.js as API. A problem that has occured recently is this error:

```
TypeError: Argument 2 of WebGLRenderingContext.uniform4fv could not be converted to any of: Float32Array, UnrestrictedFloatSequence.
```

The line in the code causing this is the basic render call of the game:

```
renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

I could now paste the messy code here but thats not why I am here. I hope somebody has ever experienced that too and can tell me what the problem is.

Note:

I. The original error is from within Three.js (The internal render stuff)

```
three.min.js:7:118
```

II.The first frame can be rendered without any problem, after that the error occurs

III. The scene is made of a few simple objects, but the source of the problem is this object:

```
this.geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(0.8, 0.8);
this.texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("graphics/racers/" + racer + ".png", function () { return;});
this.texture.generateMipmaps = false;
this.texture.minFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
this.texture.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
this.texture.repeat.set(0.25, 1);
this.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: this.texture, transparent: true });
this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(this.geometry, this.material);

scene.add(this.mesh);
```

If you need anything else feel free to ask.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I found out that the error only appears when the Mesh-Object (mentioned above) is seen by the camera!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was a fool all along ^^

I used

```
texture.offset = 0.25;
```

instead of

```
texture.offset.x = 0.25;
```

Wow! Feels great losing time for such a mistake :D Anyway: Won't do it again. A lesson for life!

Answer (score 0):

Asset loading is asynchronous and most probably your texture has not loaded by the time you are using it. Use the example at https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=TextureL#api/loaders/TextureLoader

Comment: Actually I also had this idea, so I made sure the texture was loaded before I continue. The error still occured, but I were able to find the source: the change of 'texture.offset' to e.g. '0.25' causes the rendering to fail in the next frame. I am not really sure why this is happening but I will take a look on the asynchronous loading again. (Note: When I dont apply the offset, the texture is rendered to the camera without any error (but also with no offset)). Thank you so far for your help! Very welcome!